# Using Array objects as key for ES6 Map

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, ecmascript-6, es6-map

I am trying to update my code to ES6 as I am using Node 4.0 and really like its features so far. However I have problems with the new ES6 `Map` data structure as it behaves differently to `{}` when using `Array` as a key. I am using it as a counter map.

I run this code and I would like to know how I can use arrays as keys for the `Map`.

```
"use strict";

var a = new Map();
a.set(['x','y'], 1);
console.log(a.get(['x','y']));

var b = {};
b[['x','y']] = 1;

console.log(b[['x','y']]);
```

It prints out the following and the first line should be `1` and not `undefined`:

```
undefined
1
```

The original JS map stringifies the key and I am not wanting to do the same type of stringify hack with the new ES6 `Map`.

What can I do to use arrays as keys reliably for a ES6 `Map`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Map using tuples or objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21838436/map-using-tuples-or-objects)

Comment: **TL;DR:** Collections in JavaScript **all** convert array keys to Strings... Thus you have only two possibilities: A. Use strings (considering that JS collections do this anyways, if you're doing e.g. a tuple this might not be such a bad approach, i.e. `key.split(",")[0] key.split(",")[1]`), or B. Split the array up and map and submap its elements into each other, just like anko's answer + arrayed-keyed-map does...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Understand that ES2015 Map keys are compared (almost) as if with the `===` operator. Two array instances, even if they contain the same values, do not ever compare as `===` to each other.

Try this:

```
var a = new Map(), key = ['x', 'y'];
a.set(key, 1);
console.log(a.get(key));
```

Since the Map class is intended to be usable as a base class, you could implement a subclass with an overriding `.get()` function, maybe.

(The "almost" in the first sentence is to reflect the fact that Map key equality comparison is done via `Object.is()`, which doesn't come up much in daily coding. It's essentially a *third* variation on equality testing in JavaScript.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer but overriding `.get()` is not what I want to do

Answer (score 16):

You need to save a reference to the non-primitive instance of `Array` you used as a key. Notice the difference in the following two examples:

```js
"use strict";

var a = new Map();
a.set(['x','y'], 1);
console.log(a.get(['x','y']));
console.log(['x','y'] === ['x','y']);

var b = new Map();
var array = ['x','y'];
b.set(array, 1);
console.log(b.get(array));
console.log(array === array);
```

Answer (score 14):

In case someone is looking here for a more basic approach, you can apply a custom 1-to-1 conversion of keys to strings, like in `${x}_${y}` (relying on a specific structure of keys) or `JSON.stringify(key)` (more generic) - which by no means is a perfect solution, yet it can be most reliable in many cases.

I know the OP asked for other approaches, but I think this one still needs to be mentioned here as the most direct answer to the title question.

Answer (score 13):

I also had this need, so I wrote an ISC-licensed library: [**array-keyed-map**](https://github.com/anko/array-keyed-map).  You can [find it on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/array-keyed-map).  I think [the source](https://github.com/anko/array-keyed-map/blob/8193e6c764846d4932ae071d93e1d3e63e3f24aa/main.js) is quite clear, but here's how it works anyway, for posterity:

---

Maintain a tree of `Map` objects.  Each tree stores:

- Under an internally-declared `Symbol` key: The value at that point in the tree (if any).  The `Symbol` guarantees uniqueness, so no user-provided value can overwrite this key.
- On all its other keys: all other so-far set next-trees from this tree.

For example, on `akmap.set(['a', 'b'], true)`, the internal tree structure would be like—

```
'a':
  [value]: undefined
  'b':
    [value]: true
```

Doing `akmap.set(['a'], 'okay')` after that would just change the value for the path at `'a'`:

```
'a':
  [value]: 'okay'
  'b':
    [value]: true
```

To get the value for an array, iterate through the array while reading the corresponding keys off the tree.  Return `undefined` if the tree at any point is non-existent.  Finally, read the internally declared `[value]` symbol off the tree you've gotten to.

To delete a value for an array, do the same but delete any values under the `[value]`-symbol-key, and delete any child trees after the recursive step if they ended up with a `size` of 0.

---

Why a tree?  Because it's very efficient when multiple arrays have the same prefixes, which is pretty typical in real-world use, for working with e.g. file paths.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in my case i wanted to get something like a matrix with a given value. So my first approach was to fill the map like this.

```
const matrix = new Map()
const initMatrix = () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < 20 ; i++)
        for (var j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            matrix.set([i,j], Math.random() <= 0.1)
        }
    }
}

matrix.forEach((value, key) => {
    if (value){
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)";
        ctx.fillRect(key[0] * boxWidth, key[1] * boxHeight,boxWidth, boxHeight);
    }
})
```

Everything worked fine in the beginning, but after I called the initMatrix function multiple times I fugured out, that my matrix grows after every call for 400 entries (bug? feature?). So I looked around and finally I found this site with a lot of very good solutions. But not for me :(. So after some more time I found a solution that worked for me. I just added JSON.stringify and JSON.parse to add and get the keys for the map. And that solved my problem. I hope this helps someone else to0. Maybe there are better solutions for creating a matrix but this is solution is good enough for me :). Thanks for the other posts here it saved my day :)

Here my final code:

```
const matrix = new Map()
const initMatrix = () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < 20 ; i++)
        for (var j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            matrix.set(JSON.stringify([i,j]), Math.random() <= 0.1)
        }
    }
}

matrix.forEach((value, jsonkey) => {
    if (value){
        const key = JSON.parse(jsonkey)
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)";
        ctx.fillRect(key[0] * boxWidth, key[1] * boxHeight,boxWidth, boxHeight);
    }
})
```