# strange behavior of Map()

Tags: javascript, dictionary

```
 let key = [1,2]
 let m = new Map()
 m.set(key, "12")
 console.log(m.get(key))  // 12
 console.log(m.get([1,2]))  // undefined
```

Why is it that when I want to get a value not by the name of the key variable but by the value [1,2], there is no such thing
And if you add so

```
 m.set([1,2], "12")
 m.set([1,2], "123")
 m.set([1,2], "1234")
```

about the map will be

```
Map(4) { (2) […] → "12", (2) […] → "12", (2) […] → "123", (2) […] → "1234" }​
size: 4​
<entries>​​
0: Array [ 1, 2 ] → "12"​​
1: Array [ 1, 2 ] → "12"​​
2: Array [ 1, 2 ] → "123"​​
3: Array [ 1, 2 ] → "1234"
```

Comment: That's because `[1, 2] === [1, 2]` returns `false`. Objects are compared by reference and each object literal (arrays are objects) creates a new reference to a new object.

Comment: This question is currently closed with the reason that it was not written in English.  An edit has since resolved that.  But the question should probably be marked as a duplicate of [Using Array objects as key for ES6 Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32660188/using-array-objects-as-key-for-es6-map)

Comment: there is an opportunity to use an object as a key, but there is no way to get a value from this key?

Comment: Arrays are not values.  They're objects.  Two different arrays that happen to contain the same elements are still, in fact, different arrays.  You're confusing yourself because although it may appear, because you're using an array literal, that `[1,2]` is "the same value" as some other `[1,2]` elsewhere in your code, **it's not**.  Each `[1,2]` literal becomes its own array object and they are therefore not the same key.

Comment: There are multiple ways to get the values. You can store the key objects/arrays use them or you can first get the keys from the map.

Comment: how does it make sense then to use an object as keys ?

Comment: You've showed it in your first snippet. Either store the reference or get the reference from the map with [`Map.prototype.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys)

Answer (score 0):

Keys are compared using `===` operator. Arrays are objects and `===` compares the references of objects, not their values. `[1, 2] === [1, 2]` returns `false` because each object/array literal creates a new reference to a new object. That's the reason why

```
m.set([1,2], "12")
m.set([1,2], "123")
m.set([1,2], "1234")
```

inserts three values with three different keys and why

```
m.get([1,2])
```

returns `undefined`.