# How to update the value of a javascript map with object key

Tags: javascript, dictionary, key

I have a map with an object as a key. For example: {date:"01/01/1990", idActiv:"4"}.

Then as a value, I have a string ("T" or "F") that represents True or False. My goal is to update that value, given a key.

```
var mapElem = new Map();

mapElem.set({date: "08/06/2020", idActiv: "1"}, "T");
mapElem.set({date: "18/06/2020", idActiv: "3"}, "T");
```

How I can update the map with object key {date: "08/06/2020", idActiv: "1"}?

If I do this:

```
mapElem.set({date: "08/06/2020", idActiv: "1"},"F");
```

I will have keyes repeated (Mozilla Firefox console):

```
mapElem.set({date: "08/06/2020", idActiv: "1"},"F");
Map(3)
​
size: 3
​
<entries>
​​
0: Object { date: "08/06/2020", idActiv: "1" } → "T"
​​
1: Object { date: "18/06/2020", idActiv: "3" } → "T"
​​
2: Object { date: "08/06/2020", idActiv: "1" } → "F"
​
```

Comment: Map uses a strict equality check for keys

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Array objects as key for ES6 Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32660188/using-array-objects-as-key-for-es6-map)

Comment: you can make use of `date` as a key if it's unique

Comment: Also relevant: [Map using tuples or objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21838436/map-using-tuples-or-objects). It mentions a possible solution being value objects. However, at the time that was planned for ES7 which went out years ago without this feature. [The proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-record-tuple) is currently still at stage 1.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store objects as `{date: "08/06/2020", idActiv: "1"}` lone expression creates new instance somewhere

```js
const obj1 = {date: "08/06/2020", idActiv: "1"};
const obj2 = {date: "18/06/2020", idActiv: "3"}
var mapElem = new Map();

mapElem.set(obj1, "T");
// mapElem.set(obj1.valueOf(), "T"); // equivalent
mapElem.set(obj2, "T");
// mapElem.set(obj2.valueOf(), "T"); // equivalent

mapElem.set(obj1, "F"); 
// mapElem.set(obj1.valueOf(), "F"); // equivalent

console.log([...mapElem.entries()]);
```

Comment: Thats works. But I have $.each. So if I declare only one time the reference obj1, mapElem only will have one elem.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on that?

Answer (score 0):

Since, Object is a reference type, 2 Objects even with the same properties (basically 2 identical objects) are different, as they are 2 different references.
The following should work as they are using the same Object (same reference) as a key in the map

```
var mapElem = new Map();

const key1 = {date: "08/06/2020", idActiv: "1"};
const key2 = {date: "18/06/2020", idActiv: "3"};

mapElem.set(key1, "T");
mapElem.set(key2, "T");
```

The same refernce key can be used later to update the value in the Map -

```
mapElem.set(key1,"F");
```

Alternatively, if the use case do no necessarliy require the keys to be object, you can serialize the object `JSON.stringify(object)` before using it as the key